# how to autogenerate file number in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a peoblem regarding file numbring in sharepoint . My company using a complex numbring for file and here is its format file number/month/year

Can I make a field that is autogenerate that format ? 
And if any file deleted it should rename all files after it

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options:

1. What you most probably want are unique document IDs, for that SharePoint has the so called [DocID Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee559302%28v=office.14%29.aspx). As you have custom numbering format you will need to implement a [custom document ID provider](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-sharepoint-server-2010-creating-a-custom-document-id-provider).
2. Another option is to just create event receivers for your document library. On each upload / update of a document you just create your file numbering anew based on whatever rules you desire.
3. A calculated field is the last option and it could contain a number/month/year - but you will not be able to change the file name based upon a calculated field. You could use it for filtering the document library.

I would advise you to look into event receivers or the more advanced, but complete, solution: document IDs.

Comment: Thanks for your help . Could you please explain DocID Service in details ?

Comment: Please refer to the links I provided. There is even a sample document ID service in the second link you can try out. DocID service allows you to generate unique IDs for files so you can find them easier later.